# Getting processor overflow flag in g++ or clang

Tags: c++, g++, clang

I have an integer that may have the most significant bits different or equal.

I want to chekc for that.

Actually I do:

```
struct obj{
  public: 
  Token t;
  bool isNumber(){return t<<1>>1==t;}
```

Instead I would like to do something like:

```
struct obj{
  public:
  Token t;
  bool isNumber(){t+t;return ProcessorOverflowFlag;}
```

Is there any way to do it in g++ or clang

Comment: What is `Token`? What are you trying to determine about `t`?

Comment: Token is a typedef of signed integer.

Comment: An overflow only occurs when you're doing arithmetic on two numbers. You have `t`. How are you expecting an overflow? In other words, why do you care if `t+t` overflows?

Comment: I need to contain inside an integer two things: an integer staring from -0x4000.0000 to 0x3FFF.FFFF and the others going from 0x4000.0000 to 0x7FFF.FFFF and those going from -0x8000.0000 to -0x4000.0001  . Depending on the case I will interpret the integer as number or pointer.

Comment: When the integer is between -0x4000.0000 to 0x3FFF.FFFF if it gets addeed to itself it doesn't overflow.